# Laptop battery draining fast after moving to Ubuntu

Tags: laptop, 20.04, battery

I used to have Windows 10 on my Lenovo Yoga 730-15" and recently I replaced it with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I see huge fall in discharge time to around one hour. I tried installing `powertop` and enabling `tlp` but no luck. Is this some incompatibility with my laptop and Ubuntu? Or, is there any other way I could solve this?

Comment: In addition to M.Nikjah's answer below, install TLP (see https://askubuntu.com/a/285681/100356).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is your graphic card, Nvidia? If yes, it can help:

Go to *Settings* > *Details* , and see what '*Graphics*' is your computer using. If it is Geforce, then open terminal and write

```
nvidia-settings
```

On opened window click '*PRIME Profiles*' and select '**Intel (Power Saving Mode)**'.

Restart your laptop.

Comment: Hey thank you, That helped increase my charge time to two hours from one. It used to be around 3 hours before, can we do better.. ?

Comment: thanks this was what I needed, I went from ~3hrs to 8+hrs using this. Could you summarise what the main negatives of this approach? I assume a decrease in performance?

Comment: After this step, I was not able to open nvidia-settings again. 'sudo prime-select on-demand' and restart solved my issue. Note: 'watch -d -n 0.5 nvidia-smi' can be used to monitor GPU.

Comment: The option is greyed out. :c Any idea how to make it available?

Comment: `sudo prime-select intel` will do the switch. The option is still greyed out though

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. [Laptop-mode-tools](https://www.researchut.com/tags/laptop-mode-tools/)
2. [Linux-thermal-daemon](https://01.org/linux-thermal-daemon/documentation/introduction-thermal-daemon)
3. [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/index.html)

Note: Different OS, different drivers, so we cant really do much here. I was using Windows10 which used  to give 5-6 hours of battery life and now I am using Ubuntu 20.04 as primary OS which gives 2-3 hours of battery life max. Still try above things and see how much this helps.