# How can I dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 on Dell XPS 15 9500 (Seperate SSD)?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, dell

I have recently bought a Dell XPS 15 9500 and want to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10.

I have seen some things like 'reinstall windows' or change something in Registry Editor which does not exist in my case.

What should I do to set up dual boot on this particular device?

Answer (score 1):

- For the second SSD slot, there is no screw or casing. I bought this from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DMRJPW1), which seems to work really well.
- BIOS was able to detect the second SSD, but Windows was not showing it. I used 'Disk Management' to create a full-partition on SSD. (unnecessary?)
- In BIOS, changed the setting to AHCI. Windows does not boot once you change it, however, you can boot in safe-mode. Once you boot in safe-mode, you can boot in the normal mode next time.
- Create a Bootable USB for Ubuntu.
- Install Ubuntu to your second SSD! I had no problem so far.
   (If Ubuntu does not recognize WiFi, disconnect charger and restart. Don't know why but happened only the first time.)
- [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241582/laptop-battery-draining-fast-after-moving-to-ubuntu) might help to increase battery life for Ubuntu.

F2 is for BIOS | F12 is for Booting Options